# should I use 1 3cell bms board or 3 one cell bms boards with an 18560 battery

Tags: power-supply, batteries

I have two 18560s in parallel for roughly 7A/h as a 'pack' and three packs in series with a 3 cell bms board

or

I could have a 1 cell bms board for all 6 18650s wiring the outputs from the board in the same configuration above.

I think I have mostly seen the first option and I am aware the batteries in parallel needs to be the same voltage to avoid backflow
With the second option there would be a bms between the connected batteries, would that provide any safety with backflow?

Comment: You need to use closely matched batteries in the 2P packs and use a 3 cell BMS across the 3S array.

Comment: The ideal matrix depends on the tolerance of mismatch and bypass power per cell using lossless dc-dc Balancing methods with LC storage to impede over voltage in series or over current in shunt. Does this make sense ?

Comment: _”A/h”_ is not a unit to describe a battery capacity. Ah is.